How to symbolically solve a coupled system of equations with Mathematica?
The symbolic solvers of Mathematica are strong, however, the ones fail
in some  cases, for example, for the system {x^(x + y) == y^12, y^(x + y) == x^3} over the reals.
Indeed,
Solve[{x^(x + y) == y^12, y^(x + y) == x^3}, {x, y}, Reals]


Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
Try Reduce or FindInstance instead.

and
Reduce[{x^(x + y) == y^12, y^(x + y) == x^3}, {x, y}, Reals]

and
FindInstance[{x^(x + y) == y^12, y^(x + y) == x^3}, {x, y}, Reals]

are running without  any response for hours in 14.1 on Windows 10.
The plot
ContourPlot[{x^(x + y) == y^12, y^(x + y) == x^3}, {x, -2, 5}, {y, -2,  5}]


suggets the solutions {x -> 1, y -> 1} and {x -> 4, y -> 2} , but the plot does not show
a stand alone solution {x -> 1, y -> -1}. All three solutions can be found numerically by
NSolve[{x^(x+y)==y^12,y^(x+y)==x^3,Abs[x]<=5,Abs[y]<=5},{x,y},Complexes]


{{x -> 0.633359 - 0.238871 I,  y -> 0.468235 - 0.809188 I}, {x -> 4.87806 + 0.0317266 I,  y -> 1.80523 - 1.61064 I}, {x -> 1.,  y -> 1.}, {x -> 4.87806 - 0.0317266 I,  y -> 1.80523 + 1.61064 I}, {x -> 0.633359 + 0.238871 I,  y -> 0.468235 + 0.809188 I}, {x -> 0.536597 + 0.0284836 I,  y -> -0.455244 + 0.88115 I}, {x -> 1.,  y -> -1.}, {x -> 2.58416 - 2.28479 I,  y -> -0.776203 + 0.780143 I}, {x -> -0.0133607 + 0.0251473 I,  y -> -3.55574 - 2.17787 I}, {x -> 4.,  y -> 2.}, {x -> 0.816233 + 0.244729 I,  y -> 0.81747 + 0.50487 I}, {x -> 4.57655 - 1.68878 I,  y -> 1.42345 + 1.68878 I}, {x -> 0.542606 + 0.153983 I,  y -> 0.037173 + 0.947603 I}, {x -> 0.693224 - 0.106439 I,  y -> -0.870088 + 0.513775 I}, {x -> 2.86014 - 1.25472 I,  y -> -1.1218 + 0.18289 I}, {x -> 2.86014 + 1.25472 I,  y -> -1.1218 - 0.18289 I}, {x -> 0.693224 + 0.106439 I,  y -> -0.870088 - 0.513775 I}, {x -> 0.542606 - 0.153983 I,  y -> 0.037173 - 0.947603 I}, {x -> 4.57655 + 1.68878 I,  y -> 1.42345 - 1.68878 I}, {x -> 0.816233 - 0.244729 I,  y -> 0.81747 - 0.50487 I}, {x -> -0.382865 + 0.00701507 I,  y -> -1.0598 - 0.987606 I}, {x -> 4.20838 - 2.08547 I,  y -> 2.07887 + 0.0389557 I}, {x -> -3.3177 + 1.10786 I,  y -> -0.412412 - 0.398653 I}}

, but there is a chance that there exist other sporadic real solutions.
So how to symbolically solve that system with Mathematica?

Usually: use Reduce and restrict the range where the search is done (by adding inequalities on x, y to the input). There will likely be a result, but not a particularly insightful one (in cases like this it's doubtful if one exists). This is general advice, I did not try it with your specific equations. I wouldn't be very optimistic about exhaustively listing all solutions (without restricting the range of x, y).

@Szabolcs: I tried it: Reduce[{x^(x + y) == y^12, y^(x + y) == x^3, x > 0, x < 5, y > 0,    y < 5}, {x, y}, Reals] as well as Reduce[{x^(x + y) == y^12, y^(x + y) == x^3, x > 0, x < 5, y > 0,    y < 5}, {x, y}, Complexes] is running for hours too. Thank you anyway.

The system is transcendental, not algebraic and this is the first point why we should take a closer look at the system.
It is reasonable to rewrite the system to a more comprehensible form.
$$x^{(x+y)}=\exp\left((x+y)\log\left( x\right)  \right)$$
Prescribing a condition $x>0\;$ we encounter the problem that $\log\left(x \right)\;$ is not bounded from below, moreover Log[z] has a branch cut discontinuity in the complex z plane running from -Infinity to 0. Taking the above into account we can easily find
Reduce[{ Exp[(x + y) Log[x]] == y^12, Exp[(x + y) Log[y]] == x^3, 
         10^-3 <= x <= 5, 10^-3 <= y <= 5}, {x, y}]


 (x == 1 && y == 1) || (x == 4 && y == 2)


Setting e.g. 10^-6 as a lower bound for x we might expect a longer symbolic processing.   We need not point out the expected domain Reals unless for negative arguments Log becomes complex.
Edit
Searching for larger class of solutions we could transform appropriately the original system to another form in which it might appear easier to solve. At first sight we couldn't find a more convenient form, noetheless there might be an especially suitable transformation of variables.
Another aspect is  exploiting appropriate tools in Mathematica.  Our system of equations appears to be very sensitive on varous ways we could use powerful symbolic solvers.
Reduce[{ Exp[(x + y) Log[x]] - y^12 == 0, 
         Exp[(x + y) Log[y]] - x^3 == 0, 
         -10 <= x <= 10, -10 <= y <= -1/10}, 
       {x, y}, Reals, Cubics -> True] // TraditionalForm


N @ %


( x == 1. && y == -1.) || ( x == 9. && y == -3.) || 
( x == 0.0275247 && y == -6.02752)


More diligent investigation of the system can provide further real solutions, nonetheless we need a kind of mathematical reasoning for deciding how many real solutions exist.
Let's demostrate contours of appropriate functions near the irrational solution.
ContourPlot[{Re[Exp[(x + y) Log[x]] - y^12] == 0, 
  Re[Exp[(x + y) Log[y]] - x^3] == 0, Im[Exp[(x + y) Log[y]] - x^3] == 0}, 
  {x, -1/20, 1/20}, {y, -5, -12}, 
  Evaluated -> True, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ContourStyle -> Thick, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0.02752, -6.02752}]}]


Another problem remaining is a constructive searching for complex symbolic solutions. We expect there are infinitely many complex solutions however it appears a hard task to find even a few of them. Nonetheless we can find a simple example:
With[{ x = I Exp[I Pi/6], y = -I Exp[I Pi/6]}, 
  { x^(x + y) - y^12, y^(x + y) - x^3} // Simplify]


{0, 0}



Thank you for your work. It's unclear to me why Reduce[{Exp[(x + y) Log[x]] == y^12, Exp[(x + y) Log[y]] == x^3,    10^-9 <= x <= 5, 10^-9 <= y <= 5}, {x, y}] is running without any response  for a very long time. Also a solution {x==1,y==-1} is not found.

@Artes What 's your Mathematica version? Unfortunately v12.2 doesn't evaluate your code.

In MMA 14.1.0.0, it finds Artes's solution immediately. Also a good reminder to myself that sometimes, analysis is required and I shouldn't depend on the tool to do that for me. (+1)

@UlrichNeumann I checked this calculation in M.12.3 as well as in M.130.1.

@Artes: Thank you for your investigation. How to  come to a solution { x -> 9, y -> -3 } by using that approach?

I don't know what you mean by "that approach", in the edit you have one approach, you can also try e.g.  Reduce[{Exp[(x + y) Log[x]] == y^12,  Exp[(x + y) Log[y]] == x^3, -25 <= x <= 25, -25 <= y <= 25}, {x, y}, Integers].
